# How to do fast Gauss fitting in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, math, curve-fitting

How can I do a fast Gauss fitting in C/C++? (1200 data points in a frequency of 25Hz)

Note: I'm not searching for math libaries which you can't use for commercial purpose.

Comment: GSL? It's GPL IIRC, but that doesn't preclude commercial use.

Comment: There are [contrasting points of view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License#Libraries) when libraries and GPL are involved, since it's not clear if the bundle program+library=derivative work, and thus if the program too must be licensed under the GPL.

Comment: 1200 points ought to be plenty enough just to find the sample mean and variance directly. Have you ruled this out for some reason?

Comment: I need to draw an idealistic gauss curve which fits to the data points to compare with the data sets.

Answer (score 1):

Try [the levmar C/C++ library](http://www.ics.forth.gr/~lourakis/levmar/) which is on the GNU license. Just implement your gauss model and feed it in with your starting parameters.